# AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown) | BUILD FAILED (UE 4.27 - Oculus)

Tags: android, visual-studio, unreal-engine4, oculusquest

Hello and good afternoon community,
it has now been days since I started facing the following problem and am searching for an answer still.
So let’s get things straight and try to be brief shall we?

I have recently been tasked to develop an apk, for Oculus quest 2, that can include multiplayer and of course open and customizable… kinda like I had to make google hubs using Unreal and the Meta friend system.
After some research I found out about the Shared Spaces open project Oculus made ([link to yt video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=td8dQxZY9OI)) and started researching.
Turns out they have a whole Git distribution of an Unreal Engine (version 4.27) made specifically for Oculus. So I follow along the guide under the Shared Spaces repository and proceed to clone both and install them properly.

- ([Git Shared Spaces](https://github.com/oculus-samples/Unreal-SharedSpaces))
- ([Git Unreal 4.27 Oculus](https://github.com/Oculus-VR/UnrealEngine/tree/4.27))

Everything works fine until I finally manage to load up the project via Visual Studio, rebuild the lights and try to go for an Android packaging (ASTC).
No matter what I do it will get stuck on:

*AutomationTool exiting with ExitCode=1 (Error_Unknown) | BUILD FAILED*

I don’t have a clue on what to do next, research hasn’t brought me anything on this specific instance. It seems like it can’t read symbols in some specific files, here, take a look:

- ([Error Unknown Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LE4e.png))
- ([Drive to the full Log.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QgVEwFCyb6TMXrtrJIIG3VFiHkGi_e_E/view?usp=sharing))

I will now list my system and programs:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2022
- Unreal Engine 4.27 (Git distribution - Oculus friendly)

I have already tried to:

- Re-clone both repositories (multiple times)
- Re-build the whole project (multiple times)
- Fix the files manually (trough properties and code)
- Did the whole DotNet\UnrealBuildTool.exe shenanigan (still don’t know
  what that was for but was one of the solutions I found researching)
- Went in and manually re-built singular components via Visual Studio
  (unreallightmass, automationtools, …)
- Re-installed both Android Studio and Visual Studio to check the
  settings (multiple times)

Nothing seems to be working… please help